# Android studio my service stops working after a while

Tags: java, android

Im developing an app with android studio
I have a service which connects a webpage and reads it
If webpage contains "update" then program creates a toast message. Service does it every 3 seconds.
It works good but after 20-25 minutes service stops working
How can i solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On destroy of your service:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(".RestartService");
    sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
}
```

In your manifest add a receiver:

```
        <receiver
            android:name=".ServiceReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="RestartServiceWhenStopped">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name=".RestartService"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Then, create a Java file named ServiceReceiver.java with the following code:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class ServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        context.startService(new Intent(context, BackgroundService.class));
    }
}
```

**BackgroundService is the name of your service class. This code will help you start the service automatically when it is closed by OS or even by user.

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest add a receiver:

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.admin.apptech_nation.service.AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver"/>
```

In your MainActivity you need to setRepiting Brodcast

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 Intent myIntent = new Intent(mContext, AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0, myIntent, 0);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 60); // first time
    long frequency = 60 * 50; // in ms
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), frequency, pendingIntent); 

}
```

In in your BroadcastReciver

```
public class AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    Context Mcontext;

    @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Mcontext = context;

    }
```

Comment: if you want update any UI then you can update in onReceive method it will call every 2-3 seconds  other wise you can start Intent Service in onReceive. intent service do your work and stop itself when your work finish.